# How do I delete/unregister a GitLab runner

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have registered a personal GitLab runner several months ago, which I no longer use. How do I completely delete it so that it does not show up on my GitLab CI/CD settings page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [GitLab 15.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/10/22/gitlab-15-5-released/#bulk-delete-runners-in-the-admin-area) (October 2022), you can also use the Web UI:

> ### Bulk delete runners in the Admin Area
>
> Bulk editing is a powerful and valuable feature when you need to visualize or manage large data sets. For administrators that manage a fleet of runners, the lack of a bulk delete option is a productivity drain and increases the operational overhead of maintaining runners.
>
> Now, in the Admin Area, you can select multiple runners and delete them at the same time. You can also select and delete a full page of runners at once.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_5/admin-bulk-delete-runners.png -- Bulk delete runners in the Admin Area]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/#bulk-delete-runners) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/370241).

Comment: Pretty sure this is only for self-managed so you can't use this with your own runners on Gitlab.com

Comment: @nrjohnstone This is for SaaS (gitlab.com) or self-managed GitLab instances.

Answer (score 40):

1. List runners to get their tokens and URLs:

   ```
   sudo gitlab-runner list
   ```
2. Verify with delete option specifying runner's token and URL:

   ```
   sudo gitlab-runner verify --delete -t YMsSCHnjGssdmz1JRoxx -u http://git.xxxx.com/
   ```

Comment: For this you will also need to remove it from your CI/CD page on Gitlab first

Comment: Even though the command executes successfully, the runner is still in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`, so that seemingly did nothing. The other answer here that suggests a `gitlab-runner unregister` command works for me tho.

Answer (score 25):

#### Get your runner token and id

First, go to the GitLab settings page and find the token (e.g. `250cff81` in the image below) and the id (e.g. `354472` in the image below) of the GitLab runner which you wish to delete.

[image]

#### Use the `gitlab-runner` CLI to unregister the runner

If you have access to the machine which was used to register the GitLab runner, you can unregister the runner using the following command, where you replace `{TOKEN}` with the token of your GitLab runner (e.g. `250cff81` in the example above).

```sh
gitlab-runner unregister --url https://gitlab.org/ --token {TOKEN}
```

#### Use the GitLab API to unregister the runner

If you no longer have access to the machine which was used to register the runner, or if the runner is associated with multiple projects, you can use the following Python script. Set `RUNNER_ID` to the id of your runner (e.g. `354472` in the example above) and `GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN` to a GitLab token which you can generate from your profile page.

```py
import os
import requests

GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN = ...
RUNNER_ID = ...

headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN": GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN}

r = requests.get(f"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/runners/{RUNNER_ID}", headers=headers)
runner_data = r.json()

for project in runner_data.get("projects", []):
    r = requests.delete(
        f"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{project['id']}/runners/{RUNNER_ID}",
        headers=headers,
    )
    if not r.ok:
        print("Encountered an error deleting runner from project:", r.json())

r = requests.delete(f"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/runners/{RUNNER_ID}", headers=headers)
if not r.ok:
    print("Encountered an error deleting runner:", r.json())
```

Comment: Very helpful. Use `python -m pip install requests` to install extra library - maybe should be added to the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one-liner to remove offline runners (for GitLab `14.5`):

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <private_token>" "https://<your-instance-address>/api/v4/runners/all?scope=offline&per_page=100" | jq '.[].id' | xargs -I runner_id curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <private_token>" "https://<your-instance-address>/api/v4/runners/runner_id"
```

You might run this more than once if you have more than 100 offline runners (`per_page=100`).

If you are using bash on windows (e.g. git bash), use sed to [remove trailing '\r'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660633/curl-3-url-using-bad-illegal-format-or-missing-url-in-bash-windows) from the jq result:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <private_token>" "https://<your-instance-address>/api/v4/runners/all?status=offline&per_page=100" | jq '.[].id' | sed 's/\r//' | xargs -I runner_id curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <private_token>" "https://<your-instance-address>/api/v4/runners/runner_id"
```

note: scope is [deprecated](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html#list-owned-runners), use status instead.

Comment: Most useful answer. I would just love to see: How to get the PRIVAT-TOKEN, what is your-instance-address and a link to the API documentation. Maybe an example how to delete runners on gitlab? like: curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <private_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/runners" | jq '.[].id' | xargs -I runner_id curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <private_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/runners/runner_id"

Answer (score 5):

You must make sure that you copy the value of the`token=...` entry from the `config.toml` file, or from the settings page.

**Do not** use the `registration_token` . The `registration_token` is different from the `token`.

In my case I had just created a runner, immediately realized that I had misconfigured the runner (or chosen the wrong executor), and wanted to delete it after first use:

This happened because I still had the gitlab CI/CD Settings webpage with the "Specific Runners  // Shared" Runners Section open and in focus.

I tried

```
# execute as root, presumably: 

# bad -long registration token
gitlab-runner unregister --url https://git.mycompany.de/ \
  --token GR1348941LXUymFTPN5sdKFu1F5mQ

#ERROR: Unregistering runner from GitLab forbidden   runner=GR1348941LXUymFTP
#FATAL: Failed to unregister runner  


# GOOD -shorter token from config.yml, or from this listing:
gitlab-runner list # shows name, url, token
gitlab-runner unregister --url https://git.mycompany.de/ \
  --token N8Gsyebw_mpYnUBMKB25 --name myrunner

# Unregistering runner from GitLab succeeded          runner=N8Gsyebw
```

Answer (score 3):

**If you no longer have enough information related to a runner, GitLab (UI) will only allow you to disable it.**

However, there is a workaround to delete runners via the GitLab UI (if you lost your info).

1. **Create a new blank project within GitLab (called dummy, for instance)**
2. **Go to the CI/CD settings page (Settings -> CI/CD -> Runners)**
3. **Enable all runners you want to delete to be able to edit them**
4. **Lock every runner you wish to delete to the dummy project as shown below**

[image]

5. **Delete the dummy project**

The runners are gone.

The overall idea was to lock all of the orphan runners to a dummy project, then delete that dummy.

PS: If runners are not visible in the dummy project, you may want to unlock them from the project they are associated with, then do the procedure again.

---

**EDIT:** This process is most particularly useful when

- You do not have access to the machine host (especially in big organisations where rights are segmented), only to your GitLab instance.
- You think that **creating a runner via the UI** should also give you the ability to **delete a runner via the UI**
- You have enough rights but you don't want to fire up a Ruby instance (like described in the GitLab doc) to delete a runner.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you. The server that had the runners went down and this was the easiest way to remove them from the list of "Other available runners."

Comment: Give this person a medal. And take one from GitLab for making this so gawdawful hard to do. I had dangling runners left over from a company which went out of business 3 years ago, it was absurd that there wasn't an easy way to delete the runner.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about the runners listed in "Available group runners: ...", they can be deleted at the runner settings page of your group.

Answer (score 1):

If you've deleted the specific runner in your gitlab server, try to remove the unused runner through config.toml file (locally).

To show all runners:
$ gitlab-runner list

Or
$cat /Users/yourUser/.gitlab-runner/config.toml

If you try to delete a runner with this command:

```
$ gitlab-runner verify --delete -t Token-From-Your-Runner -u https://gitlab.com/
```

-> You'll have an error (Verifying runner... error) 'cause the process doesn't not match with your remote runner...

Then (To solve this trouble)
Delete all runners by the name with their indentation!
If you only have one, the file shows as:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
```

Comment: This worked for me after trying to unregister my runners through `gitlab-runner unregister` failed repeatedly, due to the target server being a VMware Player VM that constantly changes IP because due to personal lifestyle reasons I constantly run it on different computers. So I just went to `~/.gitlab-runner/config.toml`, nuked all the runner entries from that file, created a runner on Gitlab, executed the suggested registration command, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Gitlab CLI tool (glab) is a good option here.

Steps are as follows

1. Make sure you have a token with api and write registry access and use the token to authenticate

   ```
   glab auth login
   ```
2. Use the API call to get a list of the runners and ids

   ```
   glab api runners
   ```
3. Find the ID of the runner you wish to remove and make a DELETE call to the API

   ```
   glab api -X DELETE runners/1234
   ```

You can easily wrap a script around those commands if you want to parse the JSON returned from the api runners call and remove them in bulk, check certain conditions etc...

Answer (score 1):

if anyone running into same issue here's a quick fix.

1. Unregister your runner

   ```bash
   gitlab-runner unregister --token <your_token> -u https://gitlab.com
   ```
2. Delete your runner from config.toml (you might have many)

   [image]
3. Restart

   ```bash
   gitlab-runner restart
   ```

#### A bit of explanation

If item (1)  fails that's mean your gitlab doesn't recognize your runner any more even if it still exist in your `config.toml` file. However if you restart gitlab-runner it will register again.

So, to avoid registering again, you have to unregister and delete your runner from `config.toml` file before your restart gitlab-runner.