# How can i delete old runners from gtilab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

We have some servers with the services.
A few weeks ago we moved the gitlab and the gitlab-runners from one server to another.
I have 3 online/active runners and more than 9000 old/inactive/not connected runners.

My goal is to delete all of the unnecessary runner and only see the 3 runner i'm using.

I tried do delete it with Postman API  and also unregistered and deleted all of the runners we have on the new server. From the old server everything was deleted.

If it helps on the server we have a gitlab user and a gitlab-runner user.
Both of them runs a vagrant machine with the corresponding service.
On the gitlab-runner user i have 3 machine and each of them runs 1 gitlab-runner.

Comment: See "[How do I delete/unregister a GitLab runner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74185860/6309)" with GitLab 15.5 (Oct. 2022), if it can help.