# curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL in bash Windows

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to download PDF files from a list of URLs in a .txt file, with one URL per line. ('urls.txt')

When I use the following command, where the URL I used is an exact copy-paste of the first line of the .txt file:

```
$ curl http://www.isuresults.com/results/season1617/gpchn2016/gpchn2016_protocol.pdf -o 'test.pdf'
```

the pdf downloads perfectly. However when I use this command:

```
xargs -n 1 curl -O < urls.txt
```

Then I receive a 'curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL' error x times the amount of URLs listed in the .txt file. I have tested many of the URLS individually, and they all seem to download properly.

How can I fix this?

Edit - the first three lines of urls.txt reads as follows:

```
http://www.isuresults.com/results/season1718/gpf1718/gpf2017_protocol.pdf
http://www.isuresults.com/results/season1718/gpcan2017/gpcan2017_protocol.pdf
http://www.isuresults.com/results/season1718/gprus2017/gprus2017_protocol.pdf
```

SOLVED: As per the comment below, the issue was that the .txt file was in DOS/Windows format. I converted it using the line:

```
$ dos2unix urls.txt
```

and then the files downloaded perfectly using my original line of code. See this thread for more info: [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Thank you to all who responded!

Comment: It sounds like your urls.txt file is in DOS/Windows format, which will confuse unix tools. See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) (especially Anthony Geoghegan's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
xargs -n 1 -t -a urls.txt curl -O
```

here the -a option reads list from a file rather than standard input

EDIT:

As @GordonDavisson mentioned, it looks like you may have a file with DOS line endings, you can potentially clean these up using sed before passing to xargs

```
sed 's/\r//' < urls.txt | xargs -n 1 -t curl -O
```

Comment: curl -O 'http://www.isuresults.com/results/season1617/gpchn2016/gpchn2016_protocol.pdf'$'\r'
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Comment: x times the number of URLs in the text file

Comment: can you update the question with (say the first 3) example urls from urls.txt.